# How is the Gram-Schmidt process valid? Doesn't it alter the original problem that we wanted to solve?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, orthogonality, gram-schmidt

In our numerical analysis class, we learned about **orthonormal vectors** and why they're so convenient for solving the matrix equation $A\vec{x} = \vec{b}$:

$\vec{b} = x_1\vec{a_1} + x_2\vec{a_2} + ... + x_k\vec{a_k}$

If the columns of $A$ form an orthonormal set of vectors, then we can find each $x_i$ in a stepwise fashion by "abusing" the fact that $\vec{a_i}\cdot\vec{a_j} = 0$ if $i \neq j$ and $1$ if $i = j$. For example, we can easily find $x_1$ by multiplying both sides by $a_1$:

$\vec{a_1}\cdot\vec{b} = x_1(\vec{a_1}\cdot\vec{a_1}) + x_2(\vec{a_1}\cdot\vec{a_2}) + ... + x_k(\vec{a_1}\cdot\vec{a_k}) = x_1(1) + 0 + ... + 0$.

But often times, the columns of $A$ are not orthogonal (or orthonormal). We learned the Gram-Schmidt process for transforming a given set of non-orthogonal vectors into a set of orthonormal vectors. Our instructor then told us that we can use this to solve the original problem.

Here's my issue with that: **Don't we end up solving a different problem?** The original problem asks for $A\vec{x} = \vec{b}$. If we replace $A$ with another matrix whose column vectors are orthonormal, have we not changed the problem that we're working with?

Comment: using a different basis to represent vectors doesn't change the vectors themselves

Comment: When you divide $3x=6$ by $3$, are you abusing division and changing the problem?

Comment: So the coefficients $x_1, ..., x_k$ that we get are in fact solutions to the original problem?

Comment: Separate the Gram Schmidt process from solving $Ax=b$. The Gram Schmidt process takes a collection of vectors and orthonormalises them (and with a slight modification, will remove those that already lie in the span o vectors seen so far). The process essentially creates a new, **nice** basis in which things are easier to do. Furthermore, it has nice numerical properties.

Comment: The Gram Schmidt process finds an orthogonal $Q$ and an upper triangular $R$ such that $A=QR$, then solving many problems becomes easier. $Q$ is a nice change of basis.